# Mongoose create is setting array to "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to insert a document to MongoDB using Mongoose in ES6. I have the following code to create the document:

```
    Passes.create(
        {
            passDate: '20147',
            invitedGuestPass: [{
                residentId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                residentFirstName: 'Jack',
                residentLastName: 'Smith',
                residentEmail: 'urbgfec@gmail.com',
                invitedGuestId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                invitedGuestName: request.body.guestName,
                invitedGuestNumber: request.body.guestNumber,
                invitedGuestPassScanned: false,
                invitedGuestPassSent: false
            }]
        }
    )
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

And the Schema is the following:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const invitedGuestPassesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    residentId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: [true, "Please provide and ID..."],
        unique: false
    },
    residentFirstName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide the resident's first name..."],
        unique: false
    },
    residentLastName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide the resident's last name..."],
        unique: false
    },
    residentEmail: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide the resident's email..."],
        unique: false
    },
    invitedGuestId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: [true, "Please provide and ID..."],
        unique: false
    },
    invitedGuestName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide the guest's name..."],
        unique: false
    },
    invitedGuestNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide the guest's phone number..."],
        unique: false
    },
    invitedGuestPassScanned: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: [true, "Please provide if the pass has been scanned..."],
        unique: false
    },
    invitedGuestPassSent: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: [true, "Please provide if the pass has been sent..."],
        unique: false
    },
})


const passesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    passDate: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please give date of visit..."],
        unique: true
    },
    invitedGuestPass: {
        invitedGuestPass: [invitedGuestPassesSchema],
        type: Array,
        required: [true, "Please give list of invited guests..."],
        unique: false
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model.Passes || mongoose.model("Passes", passesSchema);
```

When I run the script, the document is successfully created, but the "invitedGuestPass" array is set to undefined instead of the object that I passed in.

```
{
  passDate: '20147',
  invitedGuestPass: [ undefined ],
  _id: new ObjectId("65bda2eb1dd48467790b137e"),
  __v: 0
}
```

I'm using "mongoose": "^7.6.3",

Why is the array undefined?

I've tried simplifying the schema to be just an array of integers, and passed in [1,2,3], but that gave the same undefined array.

I've set "type" to [invitedGuestPassesSchema] in passesSchema -> invitedGuestPass and deleted "invitedGuestPass: [invitedGuestPassesSchema]". This still left it undefined.
When I set it to string and pass a string, it successfully creates the document with the correct data. So everything is correct. It's just when I pass an array that it doesn't work.

I checked that js reads the input as an array using Array.isArray(...) and it returned true.

I've tried using insert and insertOne, but it gives an error "insert is not a function..."

Answer (score 1):

change this piece of code to be like this :

```
const passesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    passDate: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please give date of visit..."],
        unique: true
    },
    invitedGuestPass: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Model_of_invitedGuestPassesSchema",
        //type: Array,
        required: [true, "Please give list of invited guests..."],
        //unique: false
    },
})
```

you're trying to create a document of `invitedGuestPassesSchema` right inside `passesSchema` while the document itself hasn't been created yet so how can Mongoose know about data that hasn't been stored yet? you have to create the document of `invitedGuestPassesSchema` first then add its `_id` to `passesSchema`.
using this approach the latter will hold documents of the other model.
I've marked `unique: false` as a comment because `false` is the default value so no need to define it unless you want it to be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested `invitedGuestPass` inside your `invitedGuestPass` property. Mongoose will default to an empty array if it cannot evaluate one from your create method execution. Change your `passesSchema` like so:

```js
const passesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    passDate: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please give date of visit..."],
        unique: true
    },
    invitedGuestPass: {
        type: [invitedGuestPassesSchema],
        required: [true, "Please give list of invited guests..."],
    },
})
```